# Python. Через RUN выдается 0, а через Debugger выдается правильный ответ. В чем причина?

Tags: python, функции

Вот где брал условие задачи: https://leetcode.com/problems/jewels-and-stones/

Начал изучать функции и хочу сделать с ее помощью. Почему-то через обычный ран программы выдается 0, а через дебаггер правильный ответ 3. В чем ошибка?

Скриншоты прикрепил, в код добавил count, чтобы более наглядно было видно, что ответы отличаются

Условие такое использую: jewels = "aA", stones = "aAAbbbb"

```
jewels = set(input())
stones = input()


def kalk(x):
    if x in jewels:
        return True


tab = []

for i in stones:
    tab.append(kalk(i))

count = tab.count(True)

print(count)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А что на вход то подаётся, на чём проверялась работа кода?

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy на литкоде не сдавал, просто сам делаю в intellij idea. Сделать через фор и обновлять счетчик понятно как, начал изучать функции и возник такой момент

Comment: У меня через IDLE тоже 3 выдается. И через PyCharm - тоже 3. Как написал @StanislavVolodarskiy, у вас "Какие-то трудности с IntelliJ Idea". Сам код нормальный относительно вашего тестового примера.

Comment: @Сергей, понял, тогда еще посмотрю, спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Вот мое решение этой задачи:

```py
jewels, stones = input('Jewels>> '), input('Stones>> ')


print(sum([stones.count(i) for i in jewels]))
```

Comment: Здесь нет ответа на заданный вопрос.

Comment: @Сергей, с чего вы взяли? Задача решена.

Comment: Вас не просили решить задачу (в данном случае, как минимум). Это же не сайт типа "Решалка" или фриланс. Вам (нам всем) был задан вопрос: "Почему-то через обычный ран программы выдается 0, а через дебаггер правильный ответ. В чем ошибка?" Ответ на него поможет автору и пополнит базу знаний. Кстати, будет тут и масса запросов на решение домашки - там такой ответ будет применим, только не рекомендую решать чужие  домашки:-)

Comment: Ошибка была в том, что нужно следовать zen of python - "простое лучше сложного"

Comment: Это - база знаний. Этот ответ, пусть и верный в обощённой ситуации, автору и остальным не поможет. И вы же не знаете, почему автор написал: "Хочу решить с созданием функции. " А ведь, скорее всего, идет отработка конкретных навыков. В такой ситуции решение без функции просто не нужно. В общем, надеюсь, я понятен. Больше вряд ли что могу сказать.

Comment: Интересно что решение в вопросе (линейное) быстрее решения в ответе (квадратичное). И ответом этот ответ не является.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy, не уточните на всякий случай, что именно ответом не является?

Comment: @Сергей, мне кажется что проблема автора вопроса в том что он нарушил правила литкода по оформлению: предоставил программу командной строки вместо тела метода с определённым имененем в классе с определённым именем. Этот ответ ничего не добавляет к вопросу: мы по прежнему имеем программу, которая рассчитана на запуск из командной строки.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy, спасибо, понятно. И теперь я узнал про существование Leetcode:-) Это полезно. Изначально я не переходил по незнакомой ссылке в вопросе.

Comment: Автор вопроса только что объяснил что я ошибся. Он и не собирался отправлять решение туда. Какие-то трудности с IntelliJ Idea.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy обновил вопрос для уточнения